# Proper docstring and type annotation in Python

Tags: python, restructuredtext, docstring

I'm seeking advice on how to properly balance the amount of information in docstrings and type hints in python. My standard would be reStructuredText docstring format and my goal is mainly to have the most efficient way to describe classes, functions and parameters and not to overdo it. In short, I want to have a balanced approach that is easy to maintain and informative / readible at the same time and most importantly I don't repeat too much after myself in those descriptions (beyond what is necessary).

Python 3.9

Example:

```
class SomeClass:

    """
    This class does this and that.
    :cvar str SOME_CLASS_VAR: <description>
    :ivar str name: <description>
    :ivar pd.DataFrame _df: <description>
    :ivar bool _ok: <description>
    :ivar tuple pos: <description>
    :vartype pos: tuple[float, float]        
    """

    SOME_CLASS_VAR = "hello"
    
    def __init__(self, name: str = "", df: Optional[pd.DataFrame] = None, ok: bool = False):
        self.name: str = name
        self._df: pd.DataFrame = df
        self._ok: bool = ok
        self.pos: tuple = (0.0, 0.0)


def some_func(mydict: dict[str, Union[str, int]], mylist: Optional[list[str]] = None) -> tuple[datetime, float, list[object]]:
    """
    This function doeas this and that.
    :param dict mydict: <description>
    :type mydict: dict[str, Union[str, int]]
    :param list mylist: <description>
    :type mylist: list[str] or None
    :return: <description>
    :rtype: tuple[datetime, float, list[object]]
    """
    some logic
```

Any feedback would be welcome from experienced developers - what is ok and what is not. What to throw out and what to simplify.

Additional questions:

1. Does it make any sense to add detailed docstring on the argument types when you already provide type annotations at title level?
2. PyCharm underlines expressions like :vartype: and :cvar: and I'm not sure why? Is it deprecated?
3. In reST docstrings in certain cases I can put all information about a variable / parameter in one line like:

   :param dict mydict: dictionary

but what is the limit for this convention?
Can I write:

```
:ivar sqlite3.Connection _conn: connection
:param pd.DataFrame df: dataframe
:param list[int] mylist: list
```

or should I break the information in :ivar:/:param: + :vartype:/:type:?

Comment: Ask about one specific problem at a time. Try to avoid questions that may be regarded as opinion-based.